# Liferay - dynamic data list get record portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

How to get  DLL record for the JSF portlet in the Liferay 7.2. I need a simple example with gradle dependency

Comment: have you tried Liferay inbuilt API ddl getRecords ?

Comment: what have you tried ? ,,  I know ddl (dynamic data lists ) ddm (dynamic data mapping )  what's dll ? something custom  or is it DDL , by the way is it from or for the portlet ?